Как сделать footer в angular приложении с динамически изменяющимся содержимым?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать следующее:
Нужен компонент/директива/иное решение, которое можно будет использовать на разных страницах, и добавлять туда разное содержимое.
Допустим у нас есть компонент-футер:
<app-footer></app-footer>

Есть три страницы-компонента:
* <app-component-A>
* <app-component-B>
* <app-component-C>

Условно стуктура компонентов такая:
Главный маршрут и компонент А (/route_A):
<app-component-A>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  <app-footer>
    <button>A</button>
  </app-footer>

</app-component-A>


Дочерний маршрут и компонент B (/route_A/route_B):
  <app-component-B>

    <app-footer>
      <button>B</button>
    </app-footer>

  </app-component-B>

В футере будут отрисованы кнопки А и В

Дочерний маршрут и компонент C (/route_A/route_C):
  <app-component-C>

    <app-footer>
      <button>C</button>
    </app-footer>

  </app-component-C>

В футере будут отрисованы кнопки А и С

Пример скорее коцептуальный!
Получается, на маршруте, где есть компонент A и компонент B будут присутствовать кнопки А и В.
А на маршруте, где есть компонент А и компонент С будут кнопки А и С соответственно.
Вопрос в том, как сделать такой комонент/директиву или что-то еще (условно app-footer), которая позволит подключать его в компонентов разных уровней, и выводить содержимое в зависимости от того какой компонент или компоненты отрендерелись?

Вопрос такой, хочется прокидывать в футер именно контент или можно обойтись данными? Например, есть список кнопок, которые в цикле отрисовываются. Тогда можно будет сделать глобальный сервис, в который компоненты будут передавать список данных для кнопки. Но можно и контентом кидаться, но это чуть сложнее. А то, что отрисовано концептуально, можно решить через ng-content. Но тоже есть свои минусы, например надо каждый раз футер вставлять, а, наверное, хочется встроить его в глобальный layout.
